# how to send large amount of data from parent to child in angular?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular10, angular12

I've a parent component in which I'm getting an object via API call. I'm then using this object in a function to get the required data. I also need this exact data in the child. This data is very large & complex and so don't know how to send it via @Input().

Currently I'm getting the data by repeating the whole process again in the child component.
It is taking too much time to render and also its not good practice.

I also tried sending the data via a service but the child component is getting rendered before it receives data from service.
Here's the code--
PARENT  COMPONENT

```
selectLanguage(id: number) {
**labelObj is coming via api**
    if (id == 2) {
      this.defaultLanguage = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.labelObj.length; i++) {
        if (this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage == '"CS+SR" - KPI') {
          this.CSSRKPILabel = this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage;
        }

        if (this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage == 'Country') {
          this.CountryLabel = this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage;
        }
        if (this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage == 'Dealer Outlet Code') {
          this.DealerOutletCodeLabel = this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage;
        }
        if (this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage == 'Switch To') {
          this.SwitchToLabel = this.labelObj[i].ConvertedLanguage;
        }
        if (this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage == 'Instant Feedback') {
          this.InstantFeedbackLabel = this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage;
        }
        if (this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage == 'Survey Feedback') {
          this.SurveyFeedbackLabel = this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage;
        }
        if (this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage == 'Service Reminders') {
          this.ServiceRemindersLabel = this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage;
        }
        if (this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage == 'Survey Analysis') {
          this.SurveyAnalysisLabel = this.labelObj[i].DefaultLanguage;
}
 }
```

Basically, I've to send the values of all these labels in the child component.
TIA.

Comment: You should really look into switch-case expressions, that code hurts my soul. Also, you can use `for(const label of this.labelObj)` and then access `label.DefaultLanguage` instead of constantly indexing.

Comment: You could consider using ngIf to avoid the child to render before you've loaded all the data. Or use ngOnChanges in the child component

Comment: I'm sorry but I promise I'm working on my coding skills.
So, should I send the data using service only ?

Comment: No problem, I was just being a bit silly, I'm sure you'll learn some better coding habits soon. You can send it through properties (and it's usually the best and easiest way), but doing it through a service should be possible too if you do it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use property binding to send one single object containing the labels to the child component.

Your function should return all the label values in one object:

```
const returnedObject: ResultObjectType | undefined = undefined;

// Function code here where this.XXXLabel is returnedObject.XXXLabel

return returnedObject;
```

In the parent component property should be defined first and initialized like this in some point of code:

```
this.resultObject = selectLanguage(); // Function returns object containing all the labels
```

Parent component template:

```
<child-component [property]="resultObject">
```

Child component ts:

```
@Input()
property: ResultObjectType | undefined = undefined;
```

ResultObjectType is the type of the object and undefined is an example of  initialization if ResultObject is not bound in the parent component.

Comment: Thank you for this, but its not the label Object I'm concerned about, its repeating the whole process in the function, in the child.
I need the values of all the labels in child too.
how do i send those ?

Comment: I edited the code. Not sure if I understand your use case right. However, my suggestion is to create another object containing all the labels the function returns and send this object to the child component.

Comment: If you need more help on this, please give us an url to Stackbliz